# Android Studio 3.1.3 Gradle build error : Transformation exception and Conflicts found in the installation area

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, build.gradle

So I am using android studio version 3.1.3, I am trying to run an app that use to work on previous versions, but now when I run it I get the follow error build error :

```
               * What went wrong:
              Execution failed for task
                ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
                 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:                                    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

First Solution I tried : the IDE was informing me, that I should replace 'compile' in build.gradle with 'implementation' so I did it, but nothing changed.

Second, I thought that my gradle was outdated, so I manually downloaded gradle version 7.7 and replaced it with the previous version of gradle (which is 4.4). I went into the gradle folder and simply removed 4.4 and copy pasted gradle 7.7. This solution also didn't work as I was getting the same error.

Last thing I tried : I attempted to update the plug-in version. It was a long shot but even the update failed to complete, I got the following message :

```
   Some conflicts  were found in the installation area
```

Here are the details in the image link : [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sXiD.jpg). I don't know what all those errors and missing component even mean to be honest.

I don't understand why this is happening, I just wanna be able to run my app normally. Its worth mentioning that it was working perfectly until I decided to update android studio to 3.1.3, then I got hit by all these gradle issues.

Please if anyone has a solution for this problem, It would be gladly appreciated, and thanks in advance.